# xamarin boot_completed crash android 8+

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently developing an Android application and I have a mysterious problem on Android 8 to 9. When I restart my phone, I receive an alert message to warn me of the failure of the application (mainly by the service started during Boot_Completed), but the services of the application are still functional. By my stack trace, I can say that the problem comes from the broadcast receiver that launches any other service.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a fix to that issue.

Below, you can see my broadcast receiver.

```
[BroadcastReceiver( Name = "com.parroinfo.SERVICE_STARTUP", Enabled = true, Exported = true, DirectBootAware = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {Intent.ActionBootCompleted, Intent.ActionLockedBootCompleted}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    class ServiceStartup : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
             if (AndroidUtils.isVersionBelow(BuildVersionCodes.O))
             {
                        context.StartService(new Intent(context, -type-));
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        context.StartForegroundService(new Intent(context, -type-));
                     }
        }
    }
```

Below, you can see my declaration on my manifest.

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.parroinfo.SERVICE_STARTUP">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Below, you can see the stack trace of the problem.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3388)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:199)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1661)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run  
(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1577)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1532)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:664)
at com.parroinfo.SERVICE_STARTUP.n_onReceive (Native Method)
at com.parroinfo.SERVICE_STARTUP.onReceive (SERVICE_STARTUP.java:29)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3379)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. the issue was caused by firebase, who's got an update who avoid to set an boot completed service. So my fix was ​​to not start the service for any android version up from marshmallow.